# How to update the UITableViewDataSource when inserting new sections or deleting sections on UITableView?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I've a UITableViewDataSource which maintains sections of data items which will be presented by an UITableView instance. The table view is editable, allowing insertion and deletion of rows and sections, and all changes on the view should be written back to the data source. After reading through the Apple documents, I can deal with insertion and deletion on rows by sending message `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` to the data source.

But, however, I can't figure out what is the standard way to feedback the changes on sections to the data source. Please kindly help.

Comment: If i understand your question (not sure if i do).
When you delete a row, you do it in a "indexpath", so, with the row as reference you must delete the item in the datasource (Array?). If you add a row you must add an item to the datasource.

Comment: @PatricioIgnacioFariaValdivi, thanks, but I'm asking on inserting / deleting sections.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Do you have sections in separated sources?

Comment: @PatricioIgnacioFariaValdivi, for the sake of simplicity, one datasource which maintains items that organized in sections.

Comment: If you have, i.e, an mutablearray with arrays for each section.
The 'numberOfSeciont', i assume, is mutablearray count.
And in "cell for row..." you do a loop for the number of section, so, if when you remove a section from table, you must remove the entire array of mutablearray and reload soto. Number of section will change and same with cellforrow. Do you understand me?

Comment: @PatricioIgnacioFariaValdivi, that's my question, how does the UITableView ask the data source to remove the entire array of mutablearray? I don't find any conformance method about inserting and deleting sections in the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Comment: But did you try that? in theory if you remove the "array section" of "data source mutable array" and then call "table view reload data" the section must be deleted/added

Comment: any standard API to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` is called by the table view to tell you what the user has done (what they have added / removed). It is then the responsibility of your code to make the appropriate changes to your Model and reload the table view.

The simplest way to reload is to call `reloadData`, and you also have more specific options for reloading / inserting / removing individual rows or sections - this is all from a UI perspective and the table view requires that you have updated your Model **before** you call any of these methods or the table view will throw an exception.

Comment: this is forRow, do you know how to deal with "forSection"?

Comment: How are you allowing the user to delete the section?

Comment: UITableView instance methods: `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` and  `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: That's how you are telling the table view what's been updated, you need to modify your Model before doing that. You need to allow the user a way to say that the section should be deleted. Maybe using section headers with buttons...

Comment: ya, header with buttons or another dialog

Comment: They will call whatever target+action you set and are unrelated to tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath. Just modify your model and call the table view as you would usually.

Comment: I'm just confused that, Apple has provided `insertSections` and `deleteSections` in the UITableView, but no corresponding methods in the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Comment: It's just a UI thing, its easy to show standard UI for row deletion but there isn't a suitable standard place to show section deletion (particularly on non-grouped table views).

Comment: thanks for providing such a great discussion for my question.